# NSURLSessionDownloadTask occasionally results in nil data

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm downloading images asynchronously from a CDN in my app (In a UICollectionView). Each time I run it, different images will fail to load. About 1-3 out of 22. Sometimes (rarely) they all load. But the point is it's not consistent. What's happening is that in this line:

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
```

`fileData` is intermittently `nil` . Strangely, `error` from the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is also `nil`. Here's the complete method:

```
+ (void) downloadFileAsynchronouslyWithUrl:(NSURL *)fileUrl andCallback:(void (^)(NSData* fileData, NSError* error))callback {
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:fileUrl completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                callback(nil, error);
            }
            else {
                NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
                if (fileData != nil) {
                    callback(fileData, nil);
                }
                else {
                    // Getting this intermittently
                    NSError *err = [self errorFromString:@"downloaded file was nil!"];
                    callback(nil, err);
                }
            }
        });
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

I have logged the status code, and it's always 200.

It is baffling me what could cause this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you scrolling while the images are being loaded? If using reusable cells, the images could be loading into the wrong cells.

Comment: @PeterTao images land in the right cells - I've traced the issue back to this method, and like I said `fileData` is resulting in nil

Comment: Does this occur while using third party libraries such as https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage?

And if the request is made through Postman are the images retrieved consistently?

Comment: @PeterTao nope, not using any third party libs.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe there are too many requests at once, and iOS can't handle that many at the same time... maybe I need to throttle them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure to move the file to something local (or load it into `NSData`) synchronously. When you return from this `downloadTaskWithURL` completion block, the file is removed. And you're attempting to read this file from within `dispatch_async`, which introduces a race condition between the grabbing of the data from the file and the OS removing this temporary file for you.

So, you might try something like:

```
+ (void) downloadFileAsynchronouslyWithUrl:(NSURL *)fileUrl andCallback:(void (^)(NSData* fileData, NSError* error))callback {
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:fileUrl completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(nil, error);
            });
        }
        else {
            NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (fileData != nil) {
                    callback(fileData, nil);
                }
                else {
                    // Getting this intermittently
                    NSError *err = [self errorFromString:@"downloaded file was nil!"];
                    callback(nil, err);
                }
            });
        }
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

Alternatively, you could consider using a `URLSessionDataTask`, which avoids this issue. We usually use download tasks when we're trying to reduce peak memory usage and/or using background sessions, but neither of those situations apply here.

Comment: That did it! Thank you.